# Получить название функции во время цикла

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть такая переменная содержащая кортеж из функций:

```
handrankorder = (royal_flush,straight_flush,four_of_a_kind,full_house,
                 flush,straight,three_of_a_kind,two_pair,
                 one_pair,high_card)

def determine_rank(hand):
    for ranker in handrankorder:
        rank = ranker(hand)

        if rank:
            break
    return rank
```

При прохождении цикла, как можно узнать какая функция на данный момент выполняется? Именно название.

Comment: `locals/globals`, но лучше сделайте словарь с именами или инкапсулируйте эту информацию в класс, например

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Решение 1

Воспользуйтесь magic-методом `__name__`. Для этого Вам следует сделать следующее:

```
def my_func():
    pass

print(my_func.__name__)
```

Proofs: [1](https://www.google.com/search?q=get%20function%20name%20python&oq=get%20function%20name%20pyt&aqs=chrome.0.0l2j69i57j0l5.5775j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251464/how-to-get-a-function-name-as-a-string)

## Решение 2

В том же кортеже задайте строковые названия функций, к которым будете обращаться в нужный момент.